# Notepad++:Is there a way to fix the fact that I can't run Chrome from the run menu?

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++

I am running Notepad++ v.5.9.2 on Windows 7-64 bit. When I try to launch files in IE or Firefox from the Run menu in N++, there's no problem. However, when I click "Launch in Chrome" nothing happens, even though I have Chrome 12 installed on my system (and it runs fine outside of Notepad++).

I tried to modify the path to Chrome in the N++ shortcuts.xml file found in the following line: "chrome "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"". I tried replacing $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) with the full path of the chrome.exe file on my machine, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem so that when I click on Run>Launch in Chrome the file will actually launch in Chrome like it does in IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While browsing another unrelated Notepad++ answer, I came across something that helped me to figure out how to work around the problem (thanks jweede!!) [Here is the documentation.](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/commands)

1. Under the Run menu, click Run.
2. Browse to wherever your Chrome executable is, mine is in `C:\Users\(current user)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
   This path will now appear in the box.
3. Put quotation marks around the entire path AND a space after the last quotation mark (important)! Then type `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`in the box, after the space.
4. Click "Run" in the dialog and it should open your current Notepad++ file in Chrome. If all is well, click "Save" and name your new shortcut and assign a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks! The final run command for Firefox is then:
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Answer (score 4):

Why did you try replacing the FULL_CURRENT_PATH part? This is for the currently opened text file.

Replace the "Chrome" part with the place where Chrome is.

Example:

`<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">&quot;c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe&quot; &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>`

Please focus the additional "`&quot;`" I put there. These are there because the path to Chrome contains spaces.

Example when used in cmd:

```
C:\>c:\programme\internet explorer\iexplore.exe
Der Befehl "c:\programme\internet" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

C:\>
```

I am using German Windows and it says it can't find the command "`c:\programme\internet`".
It thinks the command I am trying to run is "`C:\Programme\Internet`" with a parameter of "`Exporer\iexplore.exe`"

```
C:\>"c:\programme\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"

C:\>
```

This runs Internet Explorer instantly. The reason nothing comes up is that Internet Explorer just doesn't write anything to the console when starting.

Comment: @sinni800--Thanks. I thought I had fixed the chrome line in shortcuts.xml to look exactly like the command line you gave me, but it turns out I was missing the space between the path end quote and the beginning quote for $(FULL...) It doesn't work without the space!!

Comment: @sinni800--I had deleted the original "Launch in Chrome" command (which was stupid) when I did the solution below. After I did a clean reinstall to get that item back, putting `code`<Command Key="82" Shift="yes" Alt="yes" Ctrl="yes" name="Launch in Chrome">"C:\Users\Terese\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"</Command>`code` STILL doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: Really, I don't know why...

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy a Google Chrome shortcut icon into the Notepad++ folder
2. Rename it *chrome*

You will need admin approval.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Notepad++ wouldn't need the path to chrome anyway, because the Chrome installer should have added an entry to the registry under the App Paths key:

On Windows XP (and I'm assuming it would work similarly on Windows 7):

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe"
```

Should report:

```
Path        REG_SZ  C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application
<NO NAME>   REG_SZ  C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

On Windows 7 of course, that will be **C:\Users\<username>**

And on Windows 7, Chrome might be registered under the per-*user* App Paths key:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe

But as long as these are in place, and point to the Chrome executable, Notepad++ should be able to run it, unless it uses some odd way of invoking programs.

Comment: While many of these solutions will work, this is probably the most correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be a very small detail in the shortcuts.xml file. Does the chrome line look exactly like below?

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

**Edit** - Also, what exactly is the error? Is it providing an error message, silently doing nothing, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the Chrome line in the shortcuts.xml file looks just as you have it. There is no error message; it just silently does nothing.

Comment: @BenJones--Yes, the Chrome line in the shortcuts.xml file looks just as you have it. There is no error message; it just silently does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For me these not worked for windows 10. Then please Try this

View > View Current File in > Chrome.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if above tips dont work then try this:
 Copy your path to Chrome(mine was C:\Program Files x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe). Now open your Notepad++ and press F5 or select Run option from Run dropdown menu and paste this path there in double quotes . Now put a space after ending quote and put the following after space
$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).
   **IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)** .    Now save this path with any name and shortcut keys u like .

and later u can open ur document using the shortcut keys or Run dropdown menu;

```
               THANK YOU
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix

1- Save your HTML file. 
2- Go to file explorer and look for it.
3- Select it and right click to bring the menu. 
4- Choose open with and then pick your desire web app. Done.

Comment: This might be a fix - but it is unclear *why* it may be a fix. Please explain/clarify further? Thanks!